# Implement a 3D paint application: how to start?

Tags: opengl, direct3d, 3d

I want to implement a paint-like application, which will enable kids to create and work with 3 dimensional objects.

How can I start?
What is the right approach? WPF, OpenGL, or Direct3D?
(I prefer C# solutions, but C++ is OK also).

Thank you all in advance!

--NewB

Comment: Start with a design document outlining all the requirements you have, along with possible interface designs, full technical architecture, class hierarchies/designs. At that point, you might realize just how enormous of a task it is to do what you're talking about. Then, check out codeplex, search for 3D modeling application, limit the language to C#, and you'll probably find some open-source projects that are similar to what you are trying to do. Read through those and it should give you an indication of where to start.

Comment: @devinb: when someone is just starting a new, possibly experimental project in a brand-new language, the design-document-first approach isn't a very good idea, in my opinion. Design documents are more appropriate for situations where you understand both the technology and the program requirements at a very high level (a.k.a. "almost never", in my universe).

Comment: @MusiGenesis Open-ended questions like "where should I start" usually indicate that the person needs to do a little more exploration. In this case "create a 3D modeling studio in *any* language" is a pretty ridiculously large undertaking. So, starting with *any* requirements such as complete functional requirements (This is what I explicitly what I want it to do) is a good place to start. Once they have created that in low-level specifics (I want the user to be able to place a sphere, cube or pyramid on screen. The user should be able to rotate it with the mouse, etc.)

Comment: Then they will have a better delineated idea of what they need to do. (I.e. These are interface related requirements, these are interaction requirements, these are rendering speed requirements, these are IO requirements, these are physics related requirements.) They can break down those *categories* and try to find a way to get started on each individual piece.

Comment: @devinb: if I were going to start writing a 3D Paint-like application, I wouldn't have a clear idea at all of how the program would work until I played around with the code and got a good sense of what sorts of things were possible and/or practical. This is prototyping, which in my opinion is a necessary precursor to a formal design document.

Comment: @devinb: regarding his DDDraw program, I don't think this is really all that large an undertaking. If he had to do all the 3D rendering himself pixel-by-pixel, then yes, he'd probably be getting in over his head. But WPF (and other libraries) makes that part pretty easy.

Comment: @Musi I suppose it depends (as with everything) on what exactly he wants them to be able to *do* with the shapes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an excellent example using WPF you could start with:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Wpf3DPrimer.aspx

However, you should definitely keep an open mind and consider some other possibilities.  Because there are actually lots of different ways of doing this sort of thing, all of them with their own relative costs and benefits.  It's kind of like ice cream - WPF is probably like chocolate, although that might be too strong a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, you may wish to take a look at XNA too - it's a nice API that wraps up a lot of the more complex Direct3D bits and bobs and allows you to jump right in there, it's also for use with C#

Comment: riemers.net has some of the best freely available online tutorials on xna that I know.

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip all of the above, and use a higher-level API like [MOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/MOGRE) or [osgDotNet](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osgDotNet). These will let you switch between DirectX and OpenGL relatively painlessly, and semi-automatically optimize the drawing, as well as supporting quite a few features that will be quite a bit of work to do entirely on your own. You may never need the extra features, but then again you might -- and with these they're more or less thrown in for free.

Comment: @MusicGenesis:yes, the idea is that they build a graph (DAG) of the scene, with the necessary state changes reflected in the graph structure, so they (mostly) minimize the state changes necessary for the geometry you've defined.